# gmaps4rails callback doesn't always work

Tags: callback, gmaps4rails

Probably an easy question but it's been nagging at me for ages and I can't find an answer anywhere.  I'm using the gmaps4rails gem and I want to add a callback function after the map has loaded.  When I use the basic helper everything works fine, like this:

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
<% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
            alert('callback');
        }
    </script>
<% end %>
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

But if I replace <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %> with the gmaps helper, the callback doesn't happen:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => { "data" => @json }) %>
<% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
            alert('callback');
        }
    </script>
<% end %>
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

Can anyone suggest why this might happen?

Comment: there is no reason, I guess there is an issue somewhere else. Any js error?

Answer (score 0):

Of course the answer always comes the moment you pull your hair out and ask here.  The problem is the version of the gem I was using.  I still don't know why it wasn't working with 1.4.6, but 1.5.5 seems to work fine.